# Make S4 object act as an S3 class?

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I would like to write an S4 object such that it can be passed to methods that only take an S3 object.  (It seems like `setOldClass()` might be related to this but it's not clear to me from the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/setOldClass.html)?)

e.g. for a minimal example imagine I have the S3 class and function:

```
myS3 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
class(myS3) <- "myS3class"
myS3function.myS3class <- function(x) x$a + x$b
```

and I have the S4 object

```
setClass("myS4class", representation(a = "numeric", b = "numeric"))
obj <- new("myS4class", a = 1, b = 2)
```

Is there anything I can do such that

```
myS3function.myS3class(obj)
```

gives me same thing as

```
myS3function.myS3class(myS3)
```

by **modifying only the S4 class**?

**Edit** My rationale for this approach is to take advantage of all existing methods for the S3 class (that may generally come from other packages, etc) without having to rewrite them.  I realize one approach is simply to write a coercion method (`setAs()`) that would turn my S4 object into and S3 object, but then a user would always have to perform this step manually.  (While it works, I'm also a bit unclear whether it is bad practice to use `setAs()` to take an S4 class to an S3 class, rather than mapping between S4 classes).

From the way I read the documentation of `setOldClass`, it sounds like this can make S3 objects act like S4 objects?  Is that correct? If so, my question then is if it possible to do the reverse (maybe by setting the `prototype` in the S4 class?).

If this is not possible, how about an explanation of the rationale why this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a method to your S4 class to convert it to being an S3 class.

```
setGeneric(
  "as.myS3class", 
  function(object)
  {
    standardGeneric("as.myS3class")
  }  
)

setMethod(
  "as.myS3class",
  signature(object = "myS4class"),
  function(object)
  {
    structure(list(a = object@a, b = object@b), class = "myS3class")
  }
)
```

Then you can call the S3 method like this:

```
myS3function(as.myS3class(obj))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I state above, I'm really looking for a solution that would work without explicitly having to call the conversion to S3.  (e.g. it appears that we can do just that in the reverse -- have an S4 method that operates on an S3 object without explicit coercion)  If that's not possible, I'd like to understand why not a bit better....

Answer (score 2):

A successful solution is indeed buried in the documentation of `setOldClass`:

```
 ## Examples of S3 classes with guaranteed attributes
 ## an S3 class "stamped" with a vector and  a "date" attribute
 ## Here is a generator function and an S3 print method.
 ## NOTE:  it's essential that the generator checks the attribute classes
 stamped <- function(x, date = Sys.time()) {
     if(!inherits(date, "POSIXt"))
       stop("bad date argument")
     if(!is.vector(x))
       stop("x must be a vector")
     attr(x, "date") <- date
     class(x) <- "stamped"
     x
 }

 print.stamped <- function(x, ...) {
     print(as.vector(x))
     cat("Date: ",  format(attr(x,"date")), "\n")
 }

 ## Now, an S4 class with the same structure:
 setClass("stamped4", contains = "vector", representation(date = "POSIXt"))

 ## We can use the S4 class to register "stamped", with its attributes:
 setOldClass("stamped", S4Class = "stamped4")
 selectMethod("show", "stamped")
 ## and then remove "stamped4" to clean up
 removeClass("stamped4")

 someLetters <- stamped(sample(letters, 10),
                        ISOdatetime(2008, 10, 15, 12, 0, 0))

 st <- new("stamped", someLetters)
 st
 # show() method prints the object's class, then calls the S3 print method.

 stopifnot(identical(S3Part(st, TRUE), someLetters))

 # creating the S4 object directly from its data part and slots
 new("stamped", 1:10, date = ISOdatetime(1976, 5, 5, 15, 10, 0))
```

Note that the S4 object can use the S3 print method.  What surprised me is that this works for other methods that are defined for the S3 class but not the S4 class even without additional calls to `selectMethod`.  I illustrate this with a more detailed example about my use case with `ape::phylo` object here: http://carlboettiger.info/2013/10/07/nexml-phylo-class-extension.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the one function for *both* S3 and S4 classes, and not change it, you can write your own definition for `$`:

```
f <- function(x, name)
slot(x, name)

setMethod("$", signature=c(x="myS4class"), definition=f)

myS3function.myS4class(obj)
# [1] 3
```

This seems rather dubious to me, though. For starters, you'll probably also need a similar method for `[[`, since a function could reference a list element either way:

```
setMethod("[[", signature=c(x="myS4class", i="character"),
                definition=function(x, i) slot(x, i))
```

And you'll need methods for assignment as well:

```
setMethod("$<-", signature=c(x="myS4class", value="numeric"),
                 definition=function(x, name, value) `slot<-`(x, name, check=TRUE, value))

setMethod("[[<-", signature=c(x="myS4class", i="character", value="numeric"),
                  definition=function(x, i, value) `slot<-`(x, i, check=TRUE, value))
```

But then you have the problem of referencing by number:

```
obj[[1]]
# Error in obj[[1]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

So you need yet another method:

```
g <- function(x, i)
{
    slots <- names(getClass("myS4class")@slots)
    slot(x, slots[i])
}

setMethod("[[", signature=c(x="myS4class", i="numeric"), g)
```

All up, it seems like a lot of work for not much gain.

Comment: I am aware that I could go about it this way, but this is not what I am looking for.  In particular, I am looking for a solution that does not involve modifying or duplicating the existing S3 methods (Sorry I should have been clearer about this, in my question I say only: by "modifying only the S4 class").

Comment: Rewritten the answer. I think you're better off writing your own methods, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I agree that rewriting the basic methods like "$" does not sound like a good way to go.  Rewriting every single method for a class is not a solution though - dozens of packages implement 100s of functions for the object, and new ones are still added.  There's good reason for wanting an S4 version of this popular class, but it cannot happen without backward compatibility.

Comment: Is my reading of `setOldClass` correct; that we can solve the question I pose in the direction S3 -> S4 but not the reverse?  Is ordered subsetting the only reason for this?

Comment: Why don't you post exactly what this S3 class is, and why you want an S4 version of it.

Comment: The class is ape::phylo, I posted a minimal abstract example instead to illustrate the nature of the question independent from the specifics of the class, along with an analogy to an existing R function, `setOldClass`. The question is generic and not limited to a specific S3 class.